# jQuery append() adds element before all others

Tags: jquery

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
    Enter URL: <input id="addressText" type="text" style="width: 60%;"/>
    <input id="sendRequestButton" type="button" value="Get"/>
</div>
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;"></div>
```

Later, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#sendRequestButton").click(function()
    { $("#container").append("Blablabla"); }
}
```

For some reason, the new text appears before every other element on the page! What's the reason for that and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: In your code, you're not closing the #container div properly.

Comment: Expanding on what @codingsoul said: The `/>` form is only for **void elements**. `div` is not a void element. You must write an empty `div` as `<div></div>`, `<div/>` is just a start tag (despite the `/` in it). See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags But whether that's the problem, we can't tell from what you've provided. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: I added more code, but anyway, the <div></div> change didn't work.

Comment: I added your event click...and that still working. Btw, you miss some parenthesis in your code

Comment: Ok, sorry, you are right with the parentheses, but it's still not working on my browser (Firefox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, that works well with your code. Are you sure to not have an other `id="container"` somewhere?

```js
$("#sendRequestButton").click(function(){
  $("#container").append("Blablabla");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
    Enter URL: <input id="addressText" type="text" style="width: 60%;"/>
    <input id="sendRequestButton" type="button" value="Get"/>
</div>
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, it may be because you added the text right at the beginning, whilst I'm using a button click. I added it to my example, sorry I didn't specify it previously.

Comment: Sorry, I really had another "container". Foolish mistake.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :-)